# Time divided by hours/minutes

Tags: c#

How can I divide time by using intervals?

like 01:00 divided by 20 mins = 3?

06:00 divided by 2 hours = 3?

/M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work well, I suppose:

```
public static double SplitTime(TimeSpan input, TimeSpan splitSize)
{
    double msInput = input.TotalMilliseconds;
    double msSplitSize = splitSize.TotalMilliseconds;    
    return  msInput / msSplitSize;
}
```

Example; split 1 hour in 20 minute chunks:

```
double result = SplitTime(new TimeSpan(1,0,0), new TimeSpan(0,20,0));
```

I guess the method could fairly easily be reworked to return an array of `TimeSpan` objects containing the different "slices".

Answer (score 8):

I'd just use the TimeSpan object:

```
int hours = 1;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
double result = span.TotalMinutes / 20; // 3
```

Don't bother manually doing any conversions, the `TimeSpan` object with it's `TotalHours`, `TotalMinutes`, `TotalSeconds` properties, etc, do it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

First convert everything to seconds. 
  01:00 => 3600 seconds, 20 mins => 1200 seconds
then you can divide

Answer (score 0):

Convert to minutes and then do the divison.

```
h - hours
m - minutes
hd - divider hours
md - divider minutes
(h * 60 + m) / (hd * 60 + md)
```